# How to derive $SE(\hat{\beta_0}+\hat{\beta_1}x_0)=\hat{\sigma}\bigg[\frac{1}{n}+\frac{(x_0-\bar{x})^2}{(n-1)s^2_x}\bigg]^\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, regression, standard-error

I am trying to derive the following formula given by the lecture notes

$$SE(\hat{\beta_0}+\hat{\beta_1}x_0)=\hat{\sigma}\bigg[\frac{1}{n}+\frac{(x_0-\bar{x})^2}{(n-1)s^2_x}\bigg]^\frac{1}{2}$$

> [image]
> [image]

**My attempt**

$$SE(\hat{\beta_0}+\hat{\beta_1}x_0)=\big[SE^2(\hat{\beta_0})+x_0^2SE^2(\hat{\beta_1})\big]^\frac{1}{2}\\
SE^2(\hat{\beta_0})=\hat{\sigma}^2\bigg[\frac{1}{n}+\frac{\bar{x}^2}{(n-1)s^2_x}\bigg]\\
x^2_0SE^2(\hat{\beta_1})=\hat{\sigma}^2\bigg[\frac{x^2_0 }{(n-1)s^2_x}\bigg]\\
\text{Plug in}\\
SE(\hat{\beta_0}+\hat{\beta_1}x_0)=\hat{\sigma}\bigg[\frac{1}{n}+\frac{\bar{x}^2}{(n-1)s^2_x}+\frac{x^2_0}{(n-1)s^2_x}\bigg]^{\frac{1}{2}}=\hat{\sigma}\bigg[\frac{1}{n}+\frac{\color{red}{x^2_0+\bar{x}^2}}{(n-1)s^2_x}\bigg]^{\frac{1}{2}}
$$

In the correct answer, the numerator should be $(x_0-\bar{x})^2$, I don't see how can I obtained that.

Any comment are more than welcome and appreciated it for that.

Comment: When computing the standard error of $\hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta}_1x_0$, you must include the 2 $\cdot$ covariance term.